# Crystal Reports custom paper size width = 33 cm and height = 21.5 cm

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need custom paper size in Crystal Reports width = 33cm and height = 21.5cm.

I want this size to print an invoice only.
I added in the printer settings a custom paper size to add It in a report.
Put the maximum width size is 30.4cm.

So, how can I create a custom paper size by C# code, or any thing else?

[image]

Comment: repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077201/crystal-report-custom-paper-size-width-33-cm-and-height-21-5-cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .rpt file. Right click, then select design -> page setup. You could use user defined size from your printer or custom your paper size. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I already add a custom paper size to the printer and add this to the report page size . but if you try this way you will find that the maximum paper width is 30.4 cm but i want width as 33 cm .
for more details please open this link that I mention before  http://i.stack.imgur.com/nAwNw.jpg

Comment: you are using visual studio 2008. It works fine on visual studio 2010. http://i.imgur.com/oFbOB6X.png
I'am sorry. I can't help on vs2008.