# Crystal Report custom page/paper size

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I just want to print a bill in half of A4 size paper i.e. Width: 8.269 inches, Height: 5.847 inches. I have tried several times with different settings. It gets the size, but the problem is it is printing in **landscape** orientation. Just like the picture below.

[image]

Even after a massive search, I am unable to get the answer of my question. When I am writing my question, **stackoverflow** gave me some answer suggestions.

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369186/crystal-report-custom-paper-size).

But how can I get the client's printer setup in my development pc ? Is it not like generic that works fine in all printers ? If client change the printer for any reason, it will be a mess right ?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835212/programmatically-set-custom-paper-size-for-crystal-report), the problem persists and the question was not solved.

As per the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078336/crystal-report-custom-paper-size-width-33-cm-and-height-21-5-cm), I tried this process before, but failed.

I have written to [**SAP**](http://scn.sap.com/message/16058438#16058438). They answered me with a link of a file and stated it could solve my problem. I found it is a **c#** code where I am using **vb.net**. I can understand the code, but I am unable to understand from where to start.

I always use crystal reports

1. directly to the printer.....

   ```
       Dim stdata As New DataSet()
       dbcommand.Connection = conn
       dbcommand.CommandText = qry
       dbadapter.SelectCommand = dbcommand
       dbadapter.Fill(stdata)
       stdata.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath & "\ReportXml\bill.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

       Dim objRpt As New NormalSaleBill
       objRpt.SetDataSource(stdata.Tables(0))
       Dim printPages As Integer = G_DefaultPrintPages '<--- A variable with print page count 
       objRpt.PrintToPrinter(printPages, True, 0, 0)
   ```

or

2. with report viewer...

   ```
           Dim stdata As New DataSet()
       dbcommand.Connection = conn
       dbcommand.CommandText = qry
       dbadapter.SelectCommand = dbcommand
       dbadapter.Fill(stdata)
       stdata.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath & "\ReportXml\SaleBill.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

       Dim objRpt As New NormalSaleBill
       objRpt.SetDataSource(stdata.Tables(0))

       FormReport.RptViewer.ReportSource = objRpt
       FormReport.ShowDialog()
       FormReport.RptViewer.RefreshReport()
   ```

So where should I put the custom paper/page size (**If it can only be done programatically**) ?

I am totally confused. I need it badly, but I am unable to resolve it. I do not want any ready-made code. But at least a guide could help me.

For your information, I am using VB.NET 2010 with Crystal Report 13.

Comment: shouldnt you be doing that in the report itself under the Design -> Page Setup?? Also you say it always prints in Landscape, but your first image is Portrait?? Is it the other way round? have you changed orientation to what is needed in Page Setup? Also there is Margins setting that you can set to 0..

Comment: @aMazing I have tried the Design-->Page Setup. I changed the orientation into potrait, but it prints like the above image.

Comment: Dont you want to change it to Landscape?

Comment: Might be due to Printer's default settings see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835212/programmatically-set-custom-paper-size-for-crystal-report)

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem and I resolved this with the following steps.
the problem occurs due to a width greater than height. Due to that automatically rotate paper as landscape.

1.Create custom size paper in your printer

[image]

2.Crystal Reports--> Design-->Page Setup

Select your Printer with custom size paper and set orientaion.

Print!!!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try size A3 in portrait and adjust your top and bottom margins

Comment: Because you said "TRY", it doesnt look like you are sure that's an answer, this would rather be a one-liner comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the edit. I will consider that in the future